# MySQL Select row via a Regex

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how i could select a row from there table by a WHERE clause that is a contains this or >= this?

Let me explain from the start i have a logging system on my web site it save the php `$_SERVER, $_REQUEST` as JSON into fields in the table

So my Table Layout is

```
______________________________________________
|__LogId__|___server_obj___|___request_obj___|
```

now I'm trying to quest via a startDate so inside the server_obj 
So an example would be
`"REQUEST_TIME":1333907388` is in the server_obj

field how would I query for that to be > a certain number?

I'm not afraid to use StoredProcs if thats the only way but then i'm still not sure how i would do it

Comment: what is the code that you have tried ?

Comment: Is that number **always** prepended with `"REQUEST_TIME":`?

Comment: none as I don't even know where to begin I have been sat her trying to find stuff to read about it, and Yes always prepended with "REQUEST_TIME":

Comment: it would appear it's not possible i will just have to get the data into PHP and then do the filter (nasty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblname
WHERE SUBSTRING(request_obj FROM 16) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

This where the magic number `16` comes from the prefix length `"REQUEST_TIME":`

Comment: @zerkms solution's is correct but why are you storing an unnecessary string prefix in a VARCHAR field whereas you could perfectly do the same job using an UNSIGNED INT field and index that for performance. In my experience log tables can get quite big very fast, so I would suggest you do that in the long term.

Comment: For the Question i asked it was correct i had to change it slightly as i was part of a JSON object that contained that but he gave the answer that was correct for what i asked